# How to trigger click event on all buttons with a specific class in jquery

Tags: javascript

I would like to know how to trigger click event on all download buttons in jquery.

I am using WebShare from Share it and i would like to download a folder at a time because it contains many files and I can't go on downloading each file.

I tried using Downthemall but they are buttons and not links. When they are clicked the Download gets started.

Anyway, all the download buttons have the class `button-download`

and I tried the following

```
var reversed = $("button.button-download").get().reverse();

$(reversed).each(function () {
    $(this).trigger("click").delay(100);
});
```

But that downloads only the first file.
I have tried delay() so that for every download, there will be a delay so that Firefox won't get stuck. But still, it downloads only the first one and leaves the rest (i.e. doesn't click on the rest of the buttons)

I am executing the script in Inspector console of firefox.

P.S. I have looked at available answers at Stackoverflow but they didn't seem to work for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`delay` only affects animation operations.

If you want to trigger click on each of them *in sequence*, with a delay in-between, you can use `setTimeout`:

```
$("button.button-download").each(function(i) {
    var btn = $(this);
    setTimeout(btn.trigger.bind(btn, "click"), i * 100);
});
```

That queues a bunch of timers, one every 100ms, and calls `trigger("click")` on each button as the timers fire.

Whether that will actually cause the downloads the way you want is another question, but that will successfully click the buttons.

Example without downloading, and with a longer delay so you can see it running more easily:

```js
$("button.button-download").click(function() {
  console.log(this.innerHTML + " clicked");
});

$("button.button-download").each(function(i) {
    var btn = $(this);
    setTimeout(btn.trigger.bind(btn, "click"), i * 500);
});
```

```html
<button class="button-download">one</button>
<button class="button-download">two</button>
<button class="button-download">three</button>
<button class="button-download">four</button>
<button class="button-download">five</button>
<button class="button-download">six</button>
<button class="button-download">seven</button>
<button class="button-download">eight</button>
<button class="button-download">nine</button>
<button class="button-download">ten</button>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: where should I paste this code? In console it is not working. only the last file is downloaded

Comment: But.. not all are downloaded. Out of 175 items, there were only 77 items downloaded. Why is it so?

Comment: @J.Doe: Yes, the console. You may need a longer delay, or it may be that you can't download more than a certain number at a time. But the above definitely clicks the buttons.

Comment: Moreover, I am not able to see the log that the buttons are clicked. I've enabled logging in Inspector in FF

Comment: @J.Doe: If the buttons are submit buttons, this whole concept isn't going to work, because the page gets torn down when you submit a form. It may well be that you can't do what you want to do, at least not in this way.

Comment: No, they aren't submit buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.button-download').each(function(i, obj) {
    obj.trigger("click");
});
```

Comment: although `obj.click()` works  instead of `obj.trigger('click')`

Comment: ```obj.click( )``` worked for me